# How to read an object from an script of index.html in angular

Tags: json, angular

I have a object in a script in the index.html in an angular project. I need to access that object from other .ts files.

```
<script>
        var jsonData ={
   "company": 10,
   "wareHouse": 'GLV',
   "MMVNMS": 'CA',
   "OFFSITE": 'OFFSITE',
   "mualun": 'CAE', 
 }     
</script>
```

from a .ts file i want to read this jsonData object like

```
var data = jsonData;
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you could add
`declare var jsonData; // var is declared in <script>`
in the component.ts before the `@componenet` decoration

Comment: ty, this thing bugged me more than it should, really -_-

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to access it via the `window` object in any of your components like this:

```
var data = (<any>window).jsonData
```

Stackblitz is [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/am-all-imports-e1tkwf?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts).

Comment: Nice! It works like a charm. Everywhere available.